# Add custom css to theme

Tags: functions, theme-development, themes

I have WP theme and I want to add dynamic styles. I use Kirki framework. So I add code to my function.php:

```
$btn_color = get_theme_mod( 'button_color');

function my_inline_css($btn_color) {
    if ( !empty($btn_color) ) {  ?>
        .btn { background-color:<?php echo esc_attr($btn_color);?>; } <?php
    }
}
add_action('wp_head','my_inline_css');
```

But it doesn't work. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Your `$btn_color` is in the wrong place, it needs to be inside not outside the function, this is technically a basic PHP question,  you're also missing `<style>` tags

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your css goes between style tags. Try changing this line:

```
        .btn { background-color:<?php echo esc_attr($btn_color);?>; } <?php
```

to

```
        <style>.btn { background-color:<?php echo esc_attr($btn_color);?>;</style> } <?php
```